# Node.js mongojs mongoDB internet layer

Tags: node.js, mongodb, connect, network-protocols, mongojs

I have looked everywhere, cannot find what protocol the mongojs uses for connecting with the mongodb. Can anyone show me some doc's that specify if its UDP or TCP/IP or HTTP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB talks over TCP sockets. From the [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/meta-driver/latest/legacy/mongodb-wire-protocol/):

> The MongoDB Wire Protocol is a simple socket-based, request-response
>   style protocol. Clients communicate with the database server through a
>   regular TCP/IP socket.

Comment: I guess yo did'nt read on the page you linked "This legacy documentation does not necessarily reflect the current practices in MongoDB driver implementation, but may be useful for historical purposes. See the MongoDB Meta Driver for the current documentation of MongoDB driver implementation.!"

Comment: I did see that, however there are no updated docs available. I will say, having looked at the mongoDB official drivers, its clear that they utilize TCP sockets to interface with the mongoDB server. Considering all existing drivers use TCP, its hard to imagine they would change this.